# cypress selecting dates from react-calendar

Tags: cypress, react-calendar

So I have this annoying issue with the date picker from react-calendar. So the current date is 28th December 2021. I want to select a date in 4 days time.
I first have a month comparitor that checks whether the month is next month. In this case it is, so it will use the skip button to select the next month. January is now shown.
I now want to select the the 3rd of January, but it would select February instead

[image]
[image]

```
        cy.get('.react-calendar__month-view__days >')
        .not('[disabled]')
        .each((elem) => {
            if (elem.text() === nextDate.toString()) {
                elem.click();
            }
        });
```

Using the above code block it goes through each element text (which is date number) and then selects the matching number. But when it comes to having 2 of the same number displayed it fails to select the right date and chooses the following month's date
Has anyone come across a similar problem? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Closing this, I should have really saw the CSS. Theres a `aria-label="13 January 2022"` in the selector, so I can just pass the date I want to select.

```
cy.get(`[aria-label="${nextDate}"]`).click()
```